# Visual Studio Team Fundation System

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs

Colegas, tengo el siguiente problema, estoy realizando una aplicación con Visual Studio 2015 utilizando TFS para control de código.
El tema es que por motivos de arquitectura, cambié el directorio correspondiente al proyecto de la UI, el cual esta añadido al proyecto por cierto, el tema es que al momento de querer subir mis cambios al TFS, este no me deja ya que me dice: "No se ha podido encontrar parte de la ruta para TFS_Bodega/Cellar/app_start/Bundles.config", lo que me hace sentido, ya que la aplicación ahora se estructura así TFS_Bodega/1_CellarPresenteacion/Cellar/app_start/Bundles.config, lo que necesito hacer es, cambiar el archivo de configuración que le da la ruta al proyecto principal. Lo he hecho en el archivo .sln (La solución), pero al parecer el TFS no lo lee de ahí, si alguien me puede ayudar estaré muy agradecido.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, por si a alguien le ocurre, lo que hice fue hacer deshacer cambios, compilar la aplicación de nuevo y tomar los candidatos a cambios pendientes que propone el tfs. Así quedan los directorios como corresponde.

Answer (score 0):

He tenido ese problema con los repositorios de Git, también queda un archivo .git oculto en la carpeta de origen imagino que en TFS es similar, cuando he trabajado con TFS descargo los cambios a una nueva carpeta desde el repositorio eso ha funcionado para mi, es otra opción también.